# Read the contents of PDF file character-wise

Tags: c++, c++11

I wanted to read the characters of the PDF file as Unicode values and determine if it contains a Hebrew or Arabic fonts.

http://jrgraphix.net/r/Unicode/0590-05FF

http://jrgraphix.net/r/Unicode/0600-06FF

But I am struck in reading the PDF contents as Unicode values
Is there any way to read the contents of a PDF file character by character in C++?

Comment: What have you *tried*?

Comment: PDF file is an array of bytes. How you interpret those bytes is up to format specification. The question has little to do with the C++ per se.